# Type mismatch in key from map when replacing Mapper with MultithreadMapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'd like to implement a MultithreadMapper for my MapReduce job.

For this I replaced Mapper with MultithreadMapper in a working code.

Here's the exeption I'm getting:

```
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:862)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:549)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.MultithreadedMapper$SubMapRecordWriter.write(MultithreadedMapper.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.MultithreadedMapper$MapRunner.run(MultithreadedMapper.java:264)
```

Here's the code setup:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: MapReduceMain <input path> <output path>");
            System.exit(123);
        }
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(MapReduceMain.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(args[0]), job.getConfiguration());
        FileStatus[] files = fs.listStatus(new Path(args[0]));
        for(FileStatus sfs:files){
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, sfs.getPath());
        }
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(MyMultithreadMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
        MultithreadedMapper.setNumberOfThreads(job, MyMultithreadMapper.nThreads);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class); 
        job.setOutputValueClass(MyPage.class);

        job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);//write the result as sequential file

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here's the mapper's code:

```
public class MyMultithreadMapper extends MultithreadedMapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, MyPage> {

ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MyScraper>    scrapers    = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MyScraper>();

public static final int             nThreads    = 5;

public MyMultithreadMapper() {
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        scrapers.add(new MyScraper());
    }
}

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    MyScraper scraper = scrapers.poll();

    MyPage result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            result = scraper.scrapPage(value.toString(), true);
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (result == null) {
        result = new MyPage();
        result.setUrl(key.toString());
    }

    context.write(new IntWritable(result.getUrl().hashCode()), result);

    scrapers.add(scraper);
}
```

Why the hell am I getting this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what has to be done:

MultithreadedMapper.setMapperClass(job, MyMapper.class);

MyMapper must implement the map logic

MultithreadMapper must be empty