# Error when using MultithreadMapper

Tags: java, hadoop

I have got the same problem as mentioned in this question ([Type mismatch in key from map when replacing Mapper with MultithreadMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563353/type-mismatch-in-key-from-map-when-replacing-mapper-with-multithreadmapper)), but the answer do not work for me.

The error message i get looks like the following:

```
13/09/17 10:37:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201309170943_0006_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1019)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Here is my main method:

```
public static int main(String[] init_args) throws Exception {
    Configuration config = new Configuration();

    if (args.length != 5) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Arguments");
        print_usage();
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    config.set("myfirstdata", args[0]);
    config.set("myseconddata", args[1]);
    config.set("mythirddata", args[2]);
    config.set("mykeyattribute", "GK");
    config.setInt("myy", 50);
    config.setInt("myx", 49);

    // additional attributes
    config.setInt("myobjectid", 1);
    config.setInt("myplz", 3);
    config.setInt("mygenm", 4);
    config.setInt("mystnm", 6);
    config.setInt("myhsnr", 7);

    config.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ";");

    Job job = new Job(config);

    job.setJobName("MySample");

    // set the outputs for the Job
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // set the outputs for the Job
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    MultithreadedMapper.setMapperClass(job, MyMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    // In our case, the combiner is the same as the reducer. This is
    // possible
    // for reducers that are both commutative and associative
    job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[3]));
    TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[4]));

    job.setJarByClass(MySampleDriver.class);

    MultithreadedMapper.setNumberOfThreads(job, 2);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

The mapper code looks like this:

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

...

/**
 * Sets up mapper with filter geometry provided as argument[0] to the jar
 */
@Override
public void setup(Context context) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text val, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ...

    // We know that the first line of the CSV is just headers, so at byte
    // offset 0 we can just return
    if (key.get() == 0)
        return;

    String line = val.toString();
    String[] values = line.split(";");

    float latitude = Float.parseFloat(values[latitudeIndex]);
    float longitude = Float.parseFloat(values[longitudeIndex]);

    ...

    // Create our Point directly from longitude and latitude
    Point point = new Point(longitude, latitude);

    IntWritable one = new IntWritable();


    if (...) {
        int name = ...
        one.set(name);

        String out = ...
        context.write(new Text(out), one);
    } else {
        String out = ...
        context.write(new Text(out), new IntWritable(-1));
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the mapper class. You need to add `job.setMapperClass(MultithreadedMapper.class);` to your codes.